# Sending an APK via Bluetooth to another device

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer, android-bluetooth, rfcomm

I´m trying to develop an App which can send an .APK file via Bluetooth to another device with an Insecure Rfcomm connection. I´m running self-coded apps on both devices. The apps are not the same but I can still set the UUID, Rfcomm Listener and so on, so the connection should work fine and because of the insecure rfcomm without any alert to accept the transfer. I´ve tried the BluetoothChat example from the Android developer page, but I´ve got problems with changing the code for my purposes. Can anyone give me some snippets of code or any link to an tutorial how to setup Apps for Bluetooth File transfer? Every useful stuff is welcome.

EDIT:
You could say I´m trying to develop an app, which can "update" another app on another phone by Bluetooth.

Thanks

Comment: What about the Android developers page? https://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/send-files.html

Comment: unluckily i can´t use beam/nfc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
public void shareApk(Context context) {
        try {

            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
            ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);//context.getPackageName() is used for send my app's apk, you can give package name which you want to share
            File srcFile = new File(ai.sourceDir);
            Intent share = new Intent();
            share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(srcFile));
            share.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
            context.startActivity(share);
            //context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, context.getString(R.string.share_using)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ShareApp", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I´m not trying to send the apk of the app I´m using. the apk I want to send isn´t even installed on the sending phone. It´s installed on the receiver phone, so you could say I´m trying to update it with another phone and app.

Comment: Exactly, for this code apk must be installed in senders phone.

Comment: sorry but this is not what I´m looking for. as I said you could say I´m trying to develop an app which can "update" another app on another phone via Bluetooth.

Comment: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///data/app/ir.aaa.project.bbb-2/base.apk exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

Comment: @Omid If your targetSdkVersion >= 24, then we have to use FileProvider class to give access to the particular file or folder to make them accessible for other apps.